# Prove that $E[E[Y \mid X] \cdot E[Y \mid Z]] = (E[Y])^2$ if $X$ and $Z$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

$X,Y,Z$ are random variables. $Y$ is integrable. $X$ and $Z$ are independent, so the espectation of $X$ doesn't affect the expectation of $Z$.

$\sigma(\cdot)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the respective random variable. This is my resoning:

$$
\sigma(E[Y\mid X]) \subset \sigma(X)
$$
$$
\sigma(E[Y\mid Z]) \subset \sigma(Z)
$$

Then $\sigma(E[Y\mid X])$ and $\sigma(E[Y\mid Z])$ are independient too:

$$
E(E[Y\mid X]\cdot E[Y\mid Z]) = E(E[Y\mid X])\cdot E(E[Y\mid Z]) = E[Y]\cdot E[Y] = (E[Y])^2
$$

I want to know if I'm right.

Comment: While the formal proof needs $\sigma$-algebras and their independence etc., a less rigorous argument is that $E[Y\mid X]$ is a function $g(X)$ of $X$ while $E[Y\mid Z]$ is a function $h(Z)$ of $Z$. But, independence of $X$ and $Z$ implies that $g(X)$ and $h(Z)$ are independent random variables, and so $$E[g(X)h(Z)]=E[g(X)]\cdot E[h(Z)]=E[Y]\cdot E[Y] = (E[Y])^2.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are correct.